# sql pdo select menu value $_POST

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I made 2 populated selectmenu's to make queries to my sql database. The first option-tags of all select menu's have value="" Now everything works fine when I do select options of all 2 selectmenu's. But If I don't choose 1 or more options, the query doesn't work.

One of the select menu's:

```
<select name="titel" id="titel" value="">
    <option value="">Selecteer</option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option  value="'.$row['titel'].'">'.$row['titel'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Language not available</option>';
    }
    ?>
 </select>

2nd page (search.php):

<?php 
//load database connection
$host = "localhost";
$user = "...";
$password = "...";
$database_name = "...";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user,  $password, array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
// Search from MySQL database table

$titel=$_POST['titel'];
$version=$_POST['version'];

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Library  where titel = ?  AND version = ?");

$query->bindValue(1, $titel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(2, $version, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add check for that :

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Library";

if( (isset($_POST['titel']) && $_POST['titel'] != '') ) {    
  $sql .= " where titel =:titel";

  if ( (isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] != '') ) {    
    $sql .= " AND version =:version"; 
  }    
} 

if ( (isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] != '') && ! (isset($_POST['titel']) && $_POST['titel'] != '') ) {    
  $sql .= " where version =:version"; 
}

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);    

if( (isset($_POST['titel']) && $_POST['titel'] != '') ) {
   $query->bindParam(':titel', $_POST['titel']);
}

if( (isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] != '') ) {
   $query->bindParam(':version', $_POST['version']);
}

$query->execute();
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.  I'm wondering if value="" is the problem. Maybe its not interpreted as empty value but it's interpreted as quotes (strings)?

Comment: @xcx i have updated my answer check it and tell me what you get

Comment: result shows  all records in my database, so the else {... statement is executed. But that's not what I need: When I select a 'titel' ( let's say 'harry potter') and I don't select a version, the result must be all harry potter books. Not my entire library.

Comment: Seems to be very close now. When I select selectmenu 1 only: it works. When I select both menu's: it works. When I select selectmenu 2 (version), it doesnt work.

Comment: You mean select version without title or what?

Comment: What do you want to get if the user choose a version without title surely all results right?

Comment: all records from my library that have that specific version.

Comment: brilliant, you're a genius! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, Amr Aly, I made my example a bit easier by mentioning only 2 select menu's. My website uses 48 selectmenu's. I tried to experiment a bit, but it doesn't seem that it is suitable for more than 2 selectmenu's. Do you agree?

Comment: Of course I agree. You didn't mention that you have 48 selectmenues